# Castle Windsor register error with RestSharp.RestClient constructor

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor, ioc-container, restsharp

I try to register RestSharp dependencies using CastleWindsor. 
the RestClient class got three constructors:

```
public RestClient();

public RestClient(Uri baseUrl);

public RestClient(string baseUrl);
```

The problem occured when I pass parameter to constructor:

```
container.Register(Component.For<RestSharp.IRestClient>().ImplementedBy<RestSharp.RestClient>()
                .DependsOn(Dependency.OnValue("baseUrl", endpoint)));
```

The error says that it can't convert `System.String` to `System.Uri` when I pass endpoint as a string. When I pass endpoint as an Uri, error says that it can't convert `System.Uri` to `System.String`.

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Dependency.OnValue has an overload that allows you to specify a type:

```
Dependency.OnValue<System.Uri>(endpointAddress)
```